# How do I match the question mark character in a Django URL?

Tags: django, url

In my Django application, I have a URL I would like to match which looks a little like this:

```
/mydjangoapp/?parameter1=hello&parameter2=world
```

The problem here is the '?' character being a reserved regex character.

I have tried a number of ways to match this... This was my first attempt:

```
(r'^pbanalytics/log/\?parameter1=(?P<parameter1>[\w0-9-]+)&parameter2=(?P<parameter2>[\w0-9-]+), 'mydjangoapp.myFunction')
```

This was my second attempt:

```
(r'^pbanalytics/log/\\?parameter1=(?P<parameter1>[\w0-9-]+)&parameter2=(?P<parameter2>[\w0-9-]+), 'mydjangoapp.myFunction')
```

but still no luck!

Does anyone know how I might match a '?' exactly in a Django URL?

Comment: Your first attempt looks fine.

Comment: Thanks Bradley... I will try again - perhaps I got something else wrong!

Comment: IIRC, the URL dispatcher strips off the query string before matching, so a regex with a `r'\?'` in it won't match. Also, this approach is bad since, even if it worked, it not only requires both parameters but it also forces the order of the parameters.  Better to use `request.GET`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Don't. You shouldn't match query string with URL Dispatcher.
You can access all values using `request.GET` dictionary.

urls

```
(r'^pbanalytics/log/$', 'mydjangoapp.myFunction')
```

function

```
def myFunction(request) 
  param1 = request.GET.get('param1')
```

Comment: Might want a `$` at the end of the regex unless you want to match everything in the directory "pbanalytics/log/". Also, IIRC, `request.GET.get()` takes a second parameter that is the default value if the key isn't in the request.

Comment: Ahhhh..... I understand. This would actually be a far far nicer way of handling parameters to my URLs, rather than having huge regex expressions in the URL dispatcher! Thanks to you and everyone else who posted comments & answers.

Comment: Just got this implemented and it works perfectly. Thanks again all!

Comment: yeah, request.GET is basically read-only dict, so get() behaves exactly like dict's get()

Comment: @Mike: added `$` in the answer

Comment: Someone needs to add this bit of wisdom to the Django docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 3):

Django's URL patterns only match the path component of a URL. You're trying to match on the querystring as well, this is why you're having trouble. Your first regex does what you wanted, except that you should only ever be matching the path component.

In your view you can access the querystring via `request.GET`

Answer (score 2):

The `?` character is a reserved symbol in regex, yes. Your first attempt looks like proper escaping of it.

However, [`?` in a URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) is also the end of the **path** and the beginning of the **query** part (like this: `protocol://host/path/?query#hash`.
[Django's URL dispatcher](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/) doesn't let you dispatch URLs based on the query part, AFAIK.

My suggestion would be writing a django view that does the dispatching based on the  `request.GET` parameter to your view function.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do what the original question was i.e. catch-all in URL dispatch var...

```
url(r'^mens/(?P<pl_slug>.+)/$', 'main.views.mens',),
```

or

```
url(r'^mens/(?P<pl_slug>\?+)/$', 'main.views.mens',),
```

As far as *why this is needed*, GET URL's don't exactly provide good "permalinks" or good presentation in general for customers and to clients.

Clients often times request the url be formatted i.e.

```
www.example-clothing-site.com/mens/tops/shirts/t-shirts/Big_Brown_Shirt3XL
```

this is a far more readable interface for the end-user and provides a better overall presentation for the client.